# Disable URL autocomplete in the address bar?

Tags: firefox, autocomplete

With Firefox, when you type a URL in the address bar, a drop-down comes up with suggestions based on browsing history.

Firefox 15 (maybe earlier) has introduced a feature that, in addition to the drop-down actually autocompletes the URL. This is undesirable. I would like to **disable** the autocomplete while **keeping** the drop-down with suggestions, as was the case with earlier versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the browser bar, go to the website `about:config`.  You may need to click a button before you see the table of available properties.

Use the Search field to find a preference called `browser.urlbar.autoFill`.  It will likely be set to `true`.  Set it to `false`.